How to use whenever SQLERROR while executing SQL script in UNIX shell script
File name : /u02/app/scmdw/scr/appcheck.sql
Shell Script :test.ksh
#!/bin/ksh
line=sqlplus $SCMDWSA @/u02/app/scmdw/scr/appcheck.sql
echo "Result of SQL: line = $line"
could you please help me how to use 'whenever SQLERROR' while executing SQL script appcheck.sql ?, and i want to capture the error into variable 'line' if SQL script path or file name invalid

The syntax to collect SQL script output in a Bash shell (and most likely a Ksh) is:
Text=$( sqlplus $SCMDWSA @/u02/app/scmdw/scr/appcheck.sql )

However, that cannot capture any output selectively. As I previously stated, sqlplus writes everything from the whole session script to the same stdout stream. It is primarily designed for interactive use: there are all kinds of commands you need to do to stop it folding lines, injecting tabs, paginating outputs, etc. (I haven't used it for ten years, but I doubt it has improved any.)
If the session login fails, or the .sql file is not found, the output will be mercifully short. If an Oracle error arises some way into the script, the output can be huge.
I found this snippet on the Oracle documentation site:
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
begin
  SELECT COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXIST FROM DUAL;
END;
/
SELECT COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXIST FROM DUAL;
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 10:
PLS-00201: identifier 'COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXIST' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Disconnected from Oracle.....

An error in that begin/end block will terminate your session, but the log you capture will have all previous actions, data, etc. in it. If you want to automate this in a script, you need to process the whole output looking for any codes at the start of a line with three alphabetics, a hyphen, five numerics, and a colon. The letters relate to the specific Oracle component, and you have to look up the error codes in the documentation.
Google on "whenever sqlerror" takes you to the Oracle documentation, and a helpful StackOverflow site.
